# Python pip library search paths

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, lapack, cvxopt

I'm trying to install the python package [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/) via pip into a virtual environment on a Centos 6 system.

Since [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) is a prerequisite, and since I don't have superuser access to the system, I've installed lapack locally using the following:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/tom .
$ make install
```

I notice that after this step `liblapack.a` is located in my local lib directory, `/home/tom/lib`, as expected.

However, when I activate my virtual environment and run `pip install cvxopt` I get the following error:

```
<snip>
gcc -pthread -shared
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/C/base.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/C/dense.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/C/sparse.o
-L/usr/lib -L/public/apps/python/2.7.4/lib
-lm -llapack -lblas -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvxopt/base.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried adding `/home/tom/lib` to both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` but neither of these seem to affect the `gcc` command line options that `pip` is using to build the module.

Can anyone tell me how to give library search paths to `pip`? Is there a better way?

Comment: does `which ld` work?

Comment: `which ld` yields `/usr/bin/ld`. I was able to figure out my issue though. (Answer to be posted in a minute or two.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I was able to solve the problem. The first thing I had to do was enable the shared libraries for LAPACK:

```
~/src/lapack-3.5.0 $ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/tom .
~/src/lapack-3.5.0 $ make install
```

Then I exported LD_FLAGS to include the proper library search path:

```
export LD_FLAGS="-L/home/tom/lib"
```

Then I re-attempted the install of `cvxopt` from source into the virtual environment:

```
~/src/cvxopt-1.1.6 $ . venv/bin/activate
~/src/cvxopt-1.1.6 (venv)$ python setup.py build install
```

I didn't experiment with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_RUN_PATH` to determine whether they were still required with `LD_FLAGS`. However, I did determine that a shared LAPACK library was definitely required; `cvxopt` wouldn't link against the static library.